# Since which version does linux support system clock with nano precision?

Tags: linux, clock, real-time

We are using centos7 and with the date command we came to know that system clock support nano precision.

```
date +"%s %9N"
1537941601 130559008
```

So, we were to know that from which version did linux started supporting nano precision in system clock ?

Answer (score 1):

From version 2.0, since Jun, 1996.

Comment: Can you locate the exact time up to the nanosecond?  **;-) :-)  +1**